# AudioDestinationNode is not subtype of type 'void'

Tags: dart

I'm having an issue I've been unable to track down.

During runtime, the connectNode call results in an error "AudioDestinationNode is not subtype of type 'void'".

I don't have any class name conflicts, so I'm really having trouble determining where this could be coming from. Any suggestions what I should be looking for?

```
AudioBufferSourceNode source = _audioCtx.createBufferSource();        
AudioBuffer audioBuffer = _audioCtx.createBuffer(1, tempList.length , 44100);
audioBuffer.getChannelData(0).setAll(0, tempList);
source.buffer = audioBuffer;
if (_audioStart==0){
   _audioStart = _audioCtx.currentTime;
}
else{
  _audioStart += audioBuffer.duration;
}

source.connectNode(_audioCtx.destination, 0, 0);
source.start(_audioStart);
_sources.add(source);
```

Comment: Is this only in Dartium or also in Chrome, Firefox, ...?

Comment: All 3 - I've been primarily using Firefox, but I tried both of the others to see if I could get a better error message.  [edit - added]: I have the lingering suspicion that I'm having a library/package issue, but I'm not very fluent in dart, so I'm unfamiliar with the strategies for finding them here (I had to pick up the code while our dart engineer is out on sick leave).

Comment: Can you reproduce in Dartpad?

Comment: I'll give it a shot

Comment: import 'dart:web_audio';
import 'dart:typed_data';

void foo() {
Float32List tempList = new Float32List(100);
AudioContext _audioCtx = new AudioContext();
AudioBufferSourceNode source = _audioCtx.createBufferSource();        
    AudioBuffer audioBuffer = _audioCtx.createBuffer(1, tempList.length , 44100);
    audioBuffer.getChannelData(0).setAll(0, tempList);
    source.buffer = audioBuffer;
    
    source.connectNode(_audioCtx.destination, 0, 0);
    source.start(1000);
} - the console output in dartpad says "Error: ", but gives no text for me

Comment: I can't reproduce in DartPad https://dartpad.dartlang.org/be0be5e46ca5f87246acf35f1ee1a7c4

Comment: OK, my error was that I hadn't named it main() in DartPad, so the code runs there with no errors there after fixing it - but the same code in the application is still giving me the subtype error.

Comment: Weird. I'm out of ideas. Maybe report an issue in github.com/dart-lang/sdk. Please post the DartPad link there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, it's a Dart SDK issue.

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/26740

The proposed solution did fix my problem.